# Printing quoted multidimensional arrays in PHP

Tags: php

I know in PHP you can echo variables with double-quotes, but if I try to echo a multidimensional array, it doesn't work.  Like...

```
echo "Here's my variable: $array[0][name]";
```

And that outputs : "Array[name]"

Is there a way to print its value without closing the quotes?

Comment: User print_r() or var_dump() for arrays

Comment: @Konsole Sometimes we really need to use the echo with a multidimensional array (that's why I'm here). And this is a really weird behavior of PHP, which I'm still trying to understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to print its value without closing the quotes?

Yes, using [Complex (curly) syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex):

```
echo "Here's my variable: {$array[0]['name']}";
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Vkthw5)

Answer (score 1):

To print a variable inside double quote use curly braces `{}`. I cannot find the good documentation for it though.

To dump array values you can use following functions.

[print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) — Prints human-readable information about a variable

> print_r() displays information about a variable in a way that's
>   readable by humans.

[var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) — Dumps information about a variable

> This function displays structured information about one or more
>   expressions that includes its type and value. Arrays and objects are
>   explored recursively with values indented to show structure.

**EG:**

```
 print_r($array) //or
 var_dump($array)
```